# Post-apocalyptic survivors and shredded paper as currency

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, comedy

There was this series which I saw during the 90s in which there are 4 to 8 survivors after a nuclear war. the survivors consisted of elderly as well as young people.

This is all I remember about the series (since I was only a child) but yes in 1 episode they decide to have a *currency* and they use some shredded paper as currency which starts conflicts and rivalries to the extent that by the end of the episode they decide not to introduce money in their *new* society and dump all the currency into a well!

Comment: wow I also just looked for this exact show now and found this with the same description.....I loved this show as a 11 year old!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

May it can be this one?

[Woops! @ IMDB.com](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103583/)

Synopsis:

> The series centered around the six survivors of a world nuclear
>   holocaust. The six of them live together in an abandoned farm house
>   while trying to survive and re-establish civilization.

Source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woops!#Synopsis)

Comment: The show was blissfully cancelled after about 3 episodes.